# Email from Laravel are sent with a "random" sender address

Tags: php, laravel, email

For a small customer I am testing the functionalities of Krayin CRM. A Laravel based application.

Email configuration is a breeze using .env file. As per Laravel standards. 
https://krayincrm.com/how-to-manage-emails-in-krayin-crm
But I do have a problem when I send an email over Krayin CRM application. The email received does not show the sender address but a weird email address such as 1698853329@gmail.com . Below is my .env setting.

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=my_email
MAIL_PASSWORD=my_password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=my_email
MAIL_DOMAIN=gmail.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

I wonder if someone has already had this problem using KrayinCRM or in another laravel application and what is the root problem.

Comment: Note that `1698853329` is a valid UNIX timestamp that equates to `Wed Nov 01 2023 15:42:09 GMT+0000`

Comment: Also, note that `MAIL_DOMAIN` should be set to your *own* domain, not that of your SMTP service.